# MainWindow steals Keyboard focus from floating windows when clicked

Tags: wpf, focus, focusmanager, keyboardfocusmanager

I have some problems with focus on WPF. Even though focus is a common problem I couldn't find a solution that works for my problem. Here is the situation:

I have an Editor Software where I can drag documents floating (like in Visual studio). The Save buttons are displayed in the Main window above the Pane where all editor documents are hosted. Now what I would like to do is have one window floating and the other one docked in the document pane. When I want to press the Save button in the main app it steals focus from my floating window and automatically focuses the document in the document pane also the click does nothing else even when I click directly on a button.

How can I keep my application from receiving keyboard focus when there is a floating window? As I would like to keep the floating window my active window but still have access to the save buttons or the menu of the main application?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've hade the same problem. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410146/dockable-windows-floating-window-and-mainwindow-menu-integration

Comment: Hey thanks, I think that is exactly what I was looking for. I am kinda ashamed that I spend 2h searchign the web but didn't find that particular site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410146/dockable-windows-floating-window-and-mainwindow-menu-integration