# Floating window and Ribbon integration with keyboard navigation

Tags: wpf, focus, ribbon, docking, keyboard-navigation

I am working on an MDI application that has a ribbon and also supports docking/floating windows. I have troubles to keep the focus on the last floating window while accessing some commands on the ribbon.

I have found this great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410146/dockable-windows-floating-window-and-mainwindow-menu-integration) that gave me guidance.

With some modification I got my application working but later realized that I am not able to navigate the Ribbon via the keyboard anymore.

The above article suggests to set `e.Handled = true` in PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(). Unfortunately that prevents the keyboard focus to be placed onto the Ribbon and therefore navigation is not possible.

Has anybody faced this issue before?

Comment: That seems to be the gotcha to this solution for everyone. As stated in your linked post, in the comments section: "Actually, we had to handle the keyboard navigation manually in the code behind for the resource dictionary. And the code for it isn't pretty (around 850 rows). So it isn't an ideal solution but it was the only one I could think of."