# Prevent Ribbon from stealing focus from Floating Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am developing a WPF application, but since few days ago I have stucked with something.

I have successfully created some views and added a Ribbon. And everything seems to work as expected when my views are as "**Tabbed Documents**".

The problem comes when I put any view in a "**Floating**" state, when doing this, I get unable to execute any command from the Ribbon buttons to the floating window because **when I press a button in the Ribbon, my floating window inmediately loses its focus**.

I have been trying many approaches to try to solve this but with no luck.

I have even tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410146/dockable-windows-floating-window-and-mainwindow-menu-integration) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/09/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-3-focus-and-activation.aspx) solutions but, they seems to be only for WPF menus, not Ribbon (that is what I need).

I apologize for not showing any code, but I don't really have any useful code for this issue since I haven't been able to find any suitable solution for me.

Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance